# Google Forms/Sheets - How to force a copied form file with a bounded script to add a trigger for its onFormSubmit event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Basically, I want submissions from one form to create duplicates of another kind of form.

I've managed to copy the form and I have verified that it does indeed copy the bound script.

```js
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1FEVxX2-_pdeg8vN4jaUGhYbTgqVImQqdcPp5jSXkDGM");
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1XQfmJH0_CYJP9luXKQTn2JAyLsW5xeV0");
  
  var copiedFile = templateFile.makeCopy("Debriefing Teste " + classID, targetFolder);
```

However, the triggers are not copied. How can I programatically set a trigger for a form file that has just been created programatically?

EDIT: I've tried adding a trigger inside the same script, following Jescanellas tip.

```js
// This is on the same function:

  var formID = copiedFile.getId();
  
  var newForm = FormApp.openById(formID);
  
  newForm.classID = classID;

ScriptApp.newTrigger("onDebriefingSubmit")
.forForm(formID)
.onFormSubmit()
.create(); `

// Then, on the same script, a dummy code just to test it out:

function onDebriefingSubmit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('165k3ieREOPZh9JV7UstidW0z8RScB3GtSjxG_Eb7ttk');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Respostas');
  
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("teste");
} `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve my issue.

These are the important parts:

- Apparently, one script cannot set a trigger for a function inside another recently created script. It can set a trigger for a script from included libraries, but that doesn't help us.
- However, you can set a trigger inside the same script for another document (such as for another form). Thanks @Jescanellas for the tip. Whenever that form is sent, it will trigger the function inside the mother script. You gotta set up some form of garbage collection to delete the triggers, as there is a considerably low limit.
- This is the big issue: [installed triggers are disabled when created from another trigger function in V8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612). This means you have to change the runtime of the script to Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FormTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit), but take into account this will create a new Trigger in your project that will reference the next Form, which is a different project. To be more concise:

- Form A will generate a trigger for Form B, but it will be in Form A's project (still, it will work as all the Forms are from the same user).

This should be in your Form A's script, *after* the rest of your code, which I guess is in an onSubmit function:

```
var form = copiedFile.getId();
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
```

Comment: So, I have tried this, but doesn't seem to be working. I've edited my question.